# Date and time wise Sort nsmutablearray

Tags: iphone, ipad

i have one problem when i sort the NSMutablearray using date and time wise.

Does anyone have idea how can i sorted array date and time wise

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the date format 04/13/2010 which get in xml file...

NSSortDescriptor *filter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateTime" ascending:FALSE];

```
    [appDelegate.arrayWYWOMessage sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filter]];
```

but same problem, i am not getting perfect list

can you have any sample code.

Comment: [appDelegate.arrayWYWOMessage sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

Answer (score 3):

The NSArray/NSMutableArray classes contain a [method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingSelector:)...

```
- (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator
```

Which you can call passing in the following selector...

```
@selector(compare:)
```

This uses the NSDate classes compare method to perform the sorting.  An alternative would be to create a NSSortDescriptor object and pass it to the NSMutableArray's sortUsingDescriptors method.